# App similar to "I learn Chinese", but for traditional Chinese

Tags: learning, traditional-characters

I found a well crafted app named "I learn Chinese" for iPad. I like it, it seems a quality app. However, it teaches simplified Chinese characters. I'd like to learn traditional Chinese characters.

Is there a similar app for iPad to learn traditional Chinese?

Comment: This question is really about incidental knowledge and is not about Chinese language itself. Closing as offtopic. Try a forum that caters to iPad apps.

Comment: To me, this is a very valid question for a place like this, where there are people who learn, study, and already know Chinese. An iPad app can be a good tool for helping to learn Chinese, and there can be people here who can suggest quality apps for learning Chinese (because e.g. they already used this kind of apps).

Comment: Looking for learning resources is still offtopic I am sorry to inform.

Comment: @deutschZuid: I'm sorry for that. Frankly, it doesn't make sense to me. It would be much better if looking for resources for learning Chinese would be **on-topic** here.

Comment: @deutschZuid I think we should allow this kind of topic, it maybe very important to people who learn Chinese. Math.SE allow people to discuss questions about math softwares, so should we.

Comment: And @Mr.C64, I searched the APP Store, but I did not find an app. Traditional Chinese is very hard for me.

Comment: @AveMaleficum This is not for me to decide. Open a question on Meta for the mods and other regular users to mull over the options.

Comment: Check my profile for two apps that use traditional and simplified Chinese on the iTunes app store (the iPhone apps will also run on the iPad). One is free, one is not yet free but I plan to make it so during the next version.

Answer (score 1):

not an app but here is a good resource: http://eword.ntpc.edu.tw/phrase.htm

i admire you're willingness to learn traditional characters. we call these 生字簿 (unknown character booklet) in taiwanese elementary schools, so it helps if you know 注音 (zhuyin, aka ㄅㄆㄇㄈ bopomofo), and the pages flow from right to left vertically for stupid political reasons so be prepared for smudges. unfortunately the site is designed for parents and teachers, so kinda unfriendly if you don't already read chinese, but the link above should contains all the links to the pdfs. start with 一年級 (first grade) then 二年級 and so on. it's a lot to go through and meant to take six years even for kids with they sponge like memory so take it slowly, have fun!